# there was no endpoint listening at http //localhost that could accept the message

Tags: c#, wcf

I have two project in my machine. In first application i have created WCF service it works correct only i have tested, hosting in console application after hosting press Ctlr+F5 displaying message Host started @ 13-Jan-16 12:28:01 PM...

Where as in second application i am trying to add Add Service reference showing an error....

```
There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8035/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/$metadata'.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8035
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:8035/'.
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8035/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
Unable to connect to the remote server
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8035
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

App.config: host application...

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="HelloService.HelloService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="HelloService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="HelloService.IHelloService">
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8035/" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8032"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: can you just write http://localhost:8035/HelloService in your browser and check whether you see any WSDL?